# Is a representation of a Lie group determined by its weight diagram?

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading about representations of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$.  The author claims that $\mathbf{3}\otimes\bar{\mathbf{3}} = \mathbf{8}\oplus\mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{3}$ is the fundamental representation, $\bar{\mathbf{3}}$ is its conjugate, $\mathbf{8}$ is the adjoint representation and $\mathbf{1}$ is the trivial representation.  I can see that the weight diagrams for both sides agree and this is all that the author does to check the equivalence.  Is it true that a representation of a Lie algebra is determined by its weight diagram?

Comment: If "weight diagram" means what I think it means, then the answer is yes for semisimple Lie algebras but no in general. $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ is semisimple so here it's all good. But this particular isomorphism can be made very explicit; no need to use weights.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you point me to a proof of this fact?

Comment: Any textbook addressing the representation theory of Lie algebras should contain at least a statement of this result, if not a proof. Off the top of my head, try Fulton and Harris.